# C++ textbox font

Tags: c++, winapi

I made a textbox in C++ (Win32)
Now I want change the textbox form and font because it's look ugly
How I do it?

It's how I create the textbox

```
HWND WindowManager::textbox(int width, int height, int xPos, int yPos, LPCSTR content, bool edit_able)
{
    int type = (edit_able) ? (WS_CHILD|WS_VISIBLE|ES_AUTOHSCROLL) : (WS_CHILD|WS_VISIBLE|WS_HSCROLL|ES_AUTOHSCROLL);
    return CreateWindowEx(
        WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE,
        "EDIT",
        content,
        type,
        xPos,
        yPos,
        width,
        height,
        window,
        (HMENU)50,
        GetModuleHandle(NULL),
        NULL
    );
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why my edit control looks odd in my win32 c++ application using no MFC?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8695185/why-my-edit-control-looks-odd-in-my-win32-c-application-using-no-mfc)

Comment: I voted to close as a dupe of that question but actually it doesn't have a clear answer. But this one does: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1955806/how-do-i-dynamically-create-controls-with-the-same-visual-style-as-their-parent

Answer (score 1):

Several Windows controls are initialized with the ugly System font - if you want nice looking controls, you have to change the font yourself like so:

```
// create the text box
HWND hTextBox = CreateWindowEx(...);

// initialize NONCLIENTMETRICS structure
NONCLIENTMETRICS ncm;
ncm.cbSize = sizeof(ncm);

// obtain non-client metrics
SystemParametersInfo(SPI_GETNONCLIENTMETRICS, sizeof(ncm), &ncm, 0);

// create the new font
HFONT hNewFont = CreateFontIndirect(&ncm.lfMessageFont);

// set the new font
SendMessage(hTextBox, WM_SETFONT, (WPARAM)hNewFont, 0);
```

Comment: אליהו בסה: After you call `SystemParametersInfo` and before you call `CreateFontIndirect`, modify the values of the struct `ncm.lfMessageFont`?

Answer (score 0):

The `WM_SETFONT` message is what you're looking for.